# Process Scheduler heroku addon for single running scrypt restarting issue

Tags: python, heroku, schedule

I'm using the [Process Scheduler](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/process-scheduler) for running my single script every 5 hours. And it goes restarting after succesful run. Can someone help me with correct addon configuration or tell me where i'm mistaken on deploying? Much appreciated.

[The script](https://github.com/Ungaminga/youtube_vk_poster/blob/master/youtube_vk_poster.py).

Heroku logs:

`` 2018-08-03T22:06:03.958367+00:00 app[api]: Scaled to worker@0:Free by user 
2018-08-04T02:04:07.885524+00:00 app[api]: Scaled to worker@1:Free by user 
2018-08-04T02:04:11.638256+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command `python youtube_vk_poster.py`
2018-08-04T02:04:12.419358+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2018-08-04T02:04:14.723794+00:00 app[worker.1]: Getting videos for UCmxD8F_4PU22QXFVTAEzN1g, count = 91
2018-08-04T02:04:14.867784+00:00 app[worker.1]: Getting videos for UC4ec8uCUuxt08wm9kmmw6XQ, count = 16
2018-08-04T02:04:17.794132+00:00 app[worker.1]: Getting videos for UCEVZlBNhqCzDwjYTW_gXNBw, count = 399
2018-08-04T02:04:18.388777+00:00 app[worker.1]: Getting videos for UC_wfigKXaw5cHFUIgLve1Vg, count = 96
2018-08-04T02:04:19.357442+00:00 app[worker.1]: Getting videos for UCUMZybDJyqZYrj9eBx5DaSQ, count = 171
2018-08-04T02:04:20.596631+00:00 app[worker.1]: Retriving all videos from vk
2018-08-04T02:04:24.759649+00:00 app[worker.1]: Today we posted 0 videos
2018-08-04T02:04:24.775320+00:00 app[worker.1]: Posting: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oxfnR8tRQ9w
2018-08-04T02:04:26.209494+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 0
2018-08-04T02:04:26.222333+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2018-08-04T02:04:26.224327+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2018-08-04T02:04:30.004397+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command `python youtube_vk_poster.py`
2018-08-04T02:04:30.688651+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up ``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [Heroku Scheduler](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler) is a better fit here. Based on the log output (specifically, the "State changed from up to crashed"), I think "Process Scheduler" expects your script to stay alive until the *scheduler* kills it, most likely via a `scale` API call (noting that the log starts with API calls to scale from 0 to 1 instance)

If your script exits on its own, the scheduler thinks it has crashed and tries to restart it. By contrast, Heroku Scheduler expects tasks to run in burst mode - run to completion and exit. Things may get more complicated if you expect your script to take longer than 10 minutes (not a hard limit, but a recommendation in the Scheduler docs)

You *could* stick with Process Scheduler and simply make it so your script never exits - put the call to `main()` in a `while True:` loop, with an optional `time.sleep()` interval that fits your need. The scale call from Process Scheduler will kill the process with a signal. However, you'll be consuming more dyno hours that way vs. the Heroku Scheduler approach.

Comment: Is there possible to use [Heroku Scheduler](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler) every 5 hours? TY for response.

Comment: Sorry, doesn't look like it; only hourly vs. daily. If 5 hours is a hard requirement, you may need to store "last run" and exit if sufficient time has not passed. The key difference is that Scheduler will not try to re-run your process if it exits.

Comment: Still using `while(true): time.sleep(1)` [resolved my problem](https://github.com/Ungaminga/youtube_vk_poster/commit/06790cb4af9a1d0f8a4338862d3702659e35c266). Big thanks.